# Matching for case-sensitive using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

This is the Perl script:

```
my $keyword = qr/(abc|efg|xyz)/;

$subject = "ABC";
$messageBody = "ZYZ";

if ( grep{ /${keyword}/i } ( $messageBody, $subject ) ) {
    print "subject: $subject, messageBody:$messageBody \n";
}
```

How do I match for case-sensitive? It doesnt work for "ABC" but it works for "abc".

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omit `/i` regex switch,

```
if ( grep{ /$keyword/ } $messageBody, $subject ) {
```

Comment: Sure. I tried but it doesnt allow and it says a message "You can accept an answer in "so many" minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a case-insensitive modifier,

```
my $keyword = qr/(?i)(abc|efg|xyz)/;
```